# transform a differential equation to Sturm Liouville

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have to solve the following excercise:

Can this differential equation be written into Sturm-Liouville form?

$$ x^2 y'' + \alpha x y' + λ y = 0, \quad y=y(x)$$

for $0 \le x \le L$

I have reached the following solution :

$$ e^{\alpha \ln x} y'' + (a/x)e^{\alpha \ln x}y' + (λ/x^2)y = 0$$

but I do not feel it is correct, can someone guide me?

Comment: Any second order ODE of the form $y'' + a(x)y' + b(x)y = 0$ can be put in SL form by multiplying the equation by $$\exp \left ( \int a(x) dx \right)$$ So, you'll want to multiply through by the integrating factor .. (I'll leave you to determine that). The only term that is wrong in your attempt is the last one.

Comment: oh yes i have it on paper but forgot to type it : it's multiplied by e^alnx as well.so it's basically correct?

Comment: Now use your log laws to simplify $e^{\alpha \ln x}$.

Comment: Yes of course x^a. Well, thank you very much sir!